# Toggle visibility on canvas rendered svg

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, canvg

I am using canvg to render a large number of svgs onto canvases. I want these svgs to disappear/appear based on checkboxes - I've got the checkboxes bit down as well as making the svgs appear. But my question is how do I make the svgs disappear?

This is how I'm rendering the svgs:

```
if(cb.checked){
    //loops through an svg array
    if(svg has certain conditions)
        canvg('canvas1', svgs[i]);
 }
```

Now, I want to make those/some (selected) svgs that I've rendered disappear on a few conditions.  I haven't been able to get anything working, do you guys have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like Fabric.js could come in useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have an inbuilt function , If you have an id why don't you just set the display attribute of the canvas element

```
var id = 'canvas1';
var canvId  = document.getElementById(id);
if(cb.checked){
    //loops through an svg array
        canvg(id, svgs[i]);
}
else{
   canvId.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: I tried this (kudos on the else ... that didn't occur to me for some reason). But this clears out my entire canvas. I want to selectively (based on the checkboxes) choose which svg to render. Thanks though!